# Tableau - Create new table with custom text values E.g. Min, Max, Median, Average etc

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

[image]

Hi All,

I need to create table #2 (in the snapshot) based on table 1 (input) values that exist in my database. I am not sure how to create the custom fields with values Min, Max, Average, and Median. So I can at least write nested if else. I've tried paramter list but it shows max value at a time

Comment: Try out the "Show Summary" command available from the Worksheet menu. You can display multiple statistics for your measures, and the summary card will adapt to the values you select (similar to the status bar at the bottom in Excel). You can choose your statistics from the menu at the top right of the summary card. Its a useful tool - maybe not overly pretty - but useful

Comment: Does your original data have only one value for each metric/quarter? Or does it contain many values per quarter, and the values shown in your example are the aggregated values for each quarter (e.g. SUM(Sales)) In other words, what is the level of detail of your original data? Depending on the response, you might want to look into table calcs (e.g. Window_Max())

Answer (score -1):

Look at `Fixed LOD` calculations.

```
{FIXED [Quarter] : MAX([P1]) }
```

Then replace MAX with the other measures you need.

Comment: @Uday wants to calculate the max of each field across all quarters., so a LOD calc fixed to the quarter won't give the right result.

Comment: An LOD that EXCLUDEd Quarter is closer to the request, but it is still annoying to have to write 12 LOD calcs to see each combination of agg function and field

Comment: Yes. I should have done a quick version in desktop to check. I was missing the multiple measure piece which like you said would result in many calc fields.